# ZXing fails to scan barcodes on iOS

Tags: xcode4, ios4, zxing

I need to include a BArcode reader into my iPhone App and have downloaded ZXing 1.7.  When I run the test project that is included in the download, everything works fine but it simply does not recognise any barcodes. Does anybody have any experience of ZXing actually working on iPhones?

Answer (score 1):

From the zxing FAQ (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

**Why don't 1D codes work on iOS devices?**

An initial port of the Java code to C++ for 1D codes was done some time ago but has not been actively maintained. Results generated by this code are not comparable in quality or stability to the Java code. Because of this, it is disabled by default in the iOS classes. Contributors interested in improving and maintaining this code are welcome.